# Android, FaceDetection, LibC

Tags: android, face-detection

```
09-17 14:06:18.128: A/libc(27454): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1)
```

This cute error pops up whenever my application seems to recognize a face.

Code:

```
private void startFaceDetection() {
    // Try starting Face Detection
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

    // start face detection only *after* preview has started
    if (params.getMaxNumDetectedFaces() > 0) {
        // camera supports face detection, so can start it:
        mCamera.startFaceDetection();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(this);
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
}
```

And in surfaceCreated, surfaceChanged I start the face detection.

Does anyone know why this happens? Am I doing something wrong?

Open the camera, set the detection listener, rotate camera 90° so that I'm in portrait, then after surfaceview is created which is used for the preview start the detection.

Comment: To me it looks like a bug in Android: the error happens in the C library: if you did something wrong you should receive a nice exception or error code. Maybe it is triggered by something you did wrong, but still the system should report this in a better way

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. I'm testing the application on a HTC Sensation running Sense 4.1 which is a "ported rom" from another HTC phone, maybe there are some corrupted c libraries.. I'll downgrade to a lower version which is not "experimental", to see if it works then..

Answer (score 0):

here is the link might help you out,it is the best tutorial i found regarding face detection.
http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/face-detection-example-tutorials-in-android/ and
 http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/android-face-detection-example/

Comment: This project is also really good for face detection. https://github.com/ProjPossibility/2014-CSUN-Cam4Blind